# MVC Model binding JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

I have a JS file that creates a JSON string that I stringify and post with AJAX call to the server, using Fiddler I can see the JSON is formatted correctly and my Action is called as it stops at the breakpoint but my Model has just Nulls.

Here is the JS code:

```
    var testString = { id: "1", date: "28/04/2013", sim: "B787", times: "0100", note: "Test note" };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(testString),
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
        }
    });
```

And here is the Model:

```
[Serializable]
  public class BookingModel
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Sim { get; set; }
    public string Times { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
  }
```

Finally here is the Action that is called.

```
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Booking(BookingModel BookingModel)
    {

        return Json(new { sucess = 0});
    }
```

And during debug the BookingModel shows nothing but NULL's but as I mention abouve FIddler is showing the string as:

```
{"id":"1","date":"28/04/2013","sim":"B787","times":"0100","note":"Test note"}
```

I have been at this for 2 days now and I'm getting bald someone please help... It's driving me nuts.

Thanks.

Cliff.

***EDIT****

Ok bit more info looks like it does work but what I have to do is on the first breakpoint if I hit F5 to continue to the action is called again and this time the data is present and correct.

So my question now is as it works on the second round trip to the server whay not on the first?

Thanks

Cliff.

Comment: The real question is: why is the browser making two requests? Do you have some forgotten code somewhere that's invoking the same action, but without sending any data across?

Comment: Yes I found that fault it was the missing 'Return False' at the end of the function so the page was being posted by AJAX then again via the normal postback.  So thats now resolved and i get the data on the first call.  However I now find that I can get either the Data bound to my model or the other Form fields that I don't want bound but not both.... Very short hair now with this one...

Comment: You have a number of options here, but the simplest may be to include the model data on the form's action URL, and submit the form's data itself via AJAX. (You can declare the form using Ajax.Form() instead of HTML.Form())

Comment: Ok can you explain this a little further please, as I have been playing around and again all I manage to achieve it get the form data or the JSON Model bound but not both.  If it makes a difference I actually don't need it to work via AJAX as I want to take the user to another page after the data is saved, just I can't seem to work out how to bind the JSON data from a normal form, I did try putting it in a hidden input but that didn't work either.

Comment: If you know the JSON data at the time that you generate the form, you can pass each of those parameters in the URL rather than in JSON. For example: `Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new{id = 1, date = "28/04/2013", sim = "B787"})`

Answer (score 1):

Just happened to stumble across this one while I was looking for something else.

I encountered a similar thing when I first started using MVC, and it was case sensitivity that was the issue.

In your JSON Object all your property names are lower case, in your actual C# model, your property names are capitalized.

I'm going to make the assumption that a year later you've already figured this one out, but in the spirit of providing an answer for future searchers.

Try making sure that the field names in your JSON object match exactly the casing of the property names in your backing model.